# PHP/Laravel file existence verification not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `<form>` with a multiple file input that stores those files into the server. The names of the files must follow a numeric standard and that's why I rename them before storing. Each post has an ID an can have more than one file so the pattern is: post-id + dash and a number + file extension, this way, if the same post has two file with the same extensions, the dash + number will avoid them to be overwriten. So, before I store the files I run a loop to find the proper number to the name. The problem is, the function to verify the existence of the file seems not to be returning true when it should. The code:

```
$counter = 0;
do{
  $nomeArquivo = $post->id . "-{$counter}"  . "." . $arq->extension();

  $counter++;
//these commented are other ways of verification I tried
//}while(Storage::exists($nomeArquivo));
//}while(file_exists("/storage/" . $nomeArquivo));
}while(is_file("/storage/" . $post->id . "-{$counter}"));

Storage::putFileAs('/public', $arq, $nomeArquivo);
```

This code above runs inside a `foreach($files as $arq)` where `$files` are the files from the form input.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem and https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html

Comment: It's necessary to have file name as specified by you, otherwise you can use unique name to file

Comment: yes, I did it by specifying it to the variable `$nomeArquivo`. I tried with and without the full path and none worked

Comment: Your code is unlikely to work, because you're checking for the existence of a file in `/storage`, but you're then writing the file to `/public`. Use the `public_path` or `storage_path` helpers to check and store the file in the right place, if you're not using the inbuilt `Storage` or `File` facades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user @[fubar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604701/fubar) pointed in the comments, I was referencing the wrong path to verify the existence of the file. I change the while condition to `while(\File::exists(public_path() . '/storage/' . $nomeArquivo))` and it worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the File Facade to check for the existence of a file:

File::exists($myfile)

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/123/determining-if-a-file-exists

Answer (score 1):

If name of the file need to be unique only then,

You can give Unique Name like this:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
$destination ='/files/';
$filename = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
$file->move($destination, $filename);
```

Now save above file name in your database. Hope it may help you